# Twitter bootstrap, botão no titulo do panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando colocar um botão dentro do título de um *panel* do twitter bootstrap 3, porém esse botão não fica alinhado centralizado na vertical do *panel*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"> 
        Fórum
        <div class="pull-right"><button class="btn">Criar tópico</button>       </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente usar um botão menor, o que ocorre, é que as margens do `button` estão estourando a `div` do `header` do `panel`.

```
<button class="btn btn-xs">Criar tópico</button>
```

Ocorre que o botão normal é do mesmo tamanho do header de um panel, mas usando um botão do tipo extra-small fica perfeito nesta situação.

Ficaria até estranho o `header` ser muito ampliado pelas margens.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aymone/4tfuL/

Comment: Obrigado, isso resolve também.

Comment: Além disso, teria de adicionar um pouco de `css`, pois o panel não é feito para adicionar botões no `header` e sim no `body`, dá uma olhada no fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim e funcionou:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                      <div class="row"> <h3 class="col-xs-11 panel-title">Fórum</h3>
                            <div class="pull-right col-xs-1"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="border:0">Criar Tópico</a></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```